# PostgreSQL mixes schemas in two rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, database-schema

I have two completely separate Rails apps (one is Rails 3 and the other, 4).

For some weird reason, when I use a postgresql database the Rails 3 app's schema gets blended in with the Rails 4 app's schema. All these extra tables are created and its very confusing.

When I use an sqlite3 database, this doesn't happen at all.

Anybody have any experience of this?

EDIT:

For those non-psychics out there, here are the database.yml files in question:

**Rails 3 app:**

```
defaults: &defaults
  adapter: postgresql
  username: postgres
  password: password
  host: localhost

development:
  database: ct_development
  <<: *defaults
```

**Rails 4 app:**

```
defaults: &defaults
  adapter: postgresql
  username: postgres
  password: password
  host: localhost

development:
  database: po_app_dev
  <<: *defaults
```

Comment: At a guess, both apps are connecting to the same database. You would have to show your `database.yml` for both apps for any non-psychic person to be able to say for sure.